# How to fix onclick sound duration for some seconds on submit button

Tags: javascript, html

When clicking the "VOTE" button i want to play a sound and want to divert to another page. It's working, but the music doesn't play completely. It's only 4 seconds, how can I make it longer.

I tried the sleep option in button function, it is working, it holds the page and plays the sound completely. Instead of this I want to play the sound without holding the page.

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
        var bleep = new Audio();
        bleep.src = "bleep.mp3";        
</script>
```

---

**HTML**

```
<td align="center" height="50">
    <nav> <a href="#" onclick="bleep.play()"><input type="submit" name="btncandid1" value="VOTE"/></a>
</td>
```

When clicking the button I want to play the complete sound file and also want to divert to another page.

Comment: some weird looking `PHP` you got there ...

Comment: also, that code isn't Java - it's a mix of HTML and JavaScript

Comment: how long's the audio file? What is your actual question

Comment: Since you want to change page without waiting for audio, you should play the audio on NEW page instead of this one.

Comment: i aslo included my html lines in there. it is not in java ,iknow

Comment: 5 second sound file

Comment: how can i play it in new page?

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the page immediately, then trying to play the sound. But you've already gone away from the page...

To fix this, play the audio file first, then use javascript's `setTimeout()` function to wait before redirecting.

In your `<script>` tag:

```
var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.src = "bleep.mp3";

function playAudio() {
    // play audio
    bleep.play();
    // wait 5000 milliseconds (5 second), the length of your audio
    setTimeout(window.history.forward(), 5000);
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="playAudio"><input type="submit" name="btncandid1" value="VOTE"/></a>
```

Comment: its not playing

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of this I want to play the sound without holding the page.

If you want the sound file to *start* on Page A and *end* on Page B with no interruption, that's simply not possible. Moving between two pages will unload the JavaScript and cause the sound to stop playing.

The only way to potentially avoid this is to use a single-page app (or SPA), where the browser doesn't actually navigate to a different URL. Assuming this is part of a larger site, implementing an SPA would likely require a drastic overhaul of your codebase, so is probably not worth it just for a sound file.